# D3.js - Changing opacity of element on mouseover IF condition=false

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making an interactive D3.js chart with filters that display points when the user clicks the selected checkbox. Additionally, on a mouseover event a popup will appear next to the selected point with some information.

Because there is a relatively large number of points on the chart, I opted to make the relevant points transparent when the corresponding checkbox is de-selected, rather than removing the points and re-drawing them (which lags a little on slower machines).

The code I currently have for this works. The code for displaying the tooltips also works. However, they do not work well together.

When the data point is de-selected, the user cannot see it, but because it still exists the browser still displays the tooltip for the de-selected points on mouseover. Therefore I have the issue of "phantom" tooltips appearing when the user moves the mouse over a currently-transparent point.

I have tried to enclose the code that makes the tooltips appear in an `if` statement as shown below, but this does not work. Unsure if my syntax is wrong or if this behavior is not correct.

This is the original code that mostly works. Tooltips appear, the right datapoints turn transparent, but tooltips appear over transparent points.

```
    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(dataSet)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "dot")
       //other stuff goes here

        //code to make tooltip appear on mouseover
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            if(d.style("opacity", 0)=false){
                div.transition()        
                    .duration(200)      
                    .style("opacity", .8);      
                div .html(d.datetime.substring(0,10) )  
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")     
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 24) + "px");    
                }
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        })

    //code for tooltip itself
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
        .attr("class", "tooltip")               
        .style("opacity", 0);   
    });     


 //code to make de-selected points transparent
    d3.selectAll("[name=cat1]").on("change", function() {
        var selected = this.value;
        display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
    svg.selectAll(".dot")
        .filter(function(d) {return selected == d.rainSnowStatus;})
        .attr("display", display);
        });
```

This is what I tried to do (placing an if statement inside the mouseover function so it only activates when the datapoint is not transparent), but it does not work (the tooltips fail to appear altogether).

```
      //tooltip code within an if statement; does not work
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            if(svg.dot.style("opacity", 0)==false){      //  << IS THIS RIGHT?
                div.transition()        
                    .duration(200)      
                    .style("opacity", .8);      
                div .html(d.datetime.substring(0,10) )  
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")     
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 24) + "px");    
                }
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        })
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current value of the `opacity` attribute by running `d3.select(this).style("opacity")`, so to check it in your `mouseover` handler you would do

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
        if(d3.select(this).style("opacity") != 0){
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .8);      
            div .html(d.datetime.substring(0,10) )  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 24) + "px");    
            }
        })
```