# are there any way to change c3js stacked area chart opacity on mouse hover

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I have a question regarding c3.js.
Currently, we are using c3js to display a stacked area chart, that is pretty fine, but our client asked us if we can change the individual area's opacity when customer is mouse hovering one area.
I could not find any solution for this, and hope to hear your suggetions.
Thanks

Comment: Do you refer to [this graph](https://c3js.org/samples/chart_area_stacked.html) from [c3 examples](https://c3js.org/examples.html)?

Comment: Yes, but that graph has no visual effect change on hovering on different area. I want to apply some visual change when user hover on various part of area.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066259/d3-js-changing-opacity-of-element-on-mouseover-if-condition-false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this after you've set up your chart -->

```
d3.selectAll(".c3-area")
    .style ("pointer-events", "all")
    .on("mouseover", function (d) { return d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.6)})
    .on("mouseout", function (d) { return d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.2)})
;
```

The pointer-events setting is the important bit as by default most of the elements in the c3 chart are styled to ignore them.

Add it to the end of the c3 example to see it working --> https://c3js.org/samples/chart_area.html